# how to make auto complete of an email ID from bbdb? emacs/gnus

Tags: emacs, gnus

I am looking for bbdb/gnus integration. could anyone share their setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some stuff which I use to automatically update the address book and use it for completing the To: and CC: fields automatically over [here](https://github.com/nibrahim/Config-files/blob/master/emacs/.gnus#L261). It is however picked up over the years from various places so I'm not sure of the details.

Comment: thaks for the reply. the setup, it may be good if you read mails, its painful if you read news. you dont want to add those unknown email ids into your database.!!. what I want is when i compose a mail email id has to complete automatically complete from the bbdb, if it can use ido, that would be more useful.

Comment: WEll, you can comment out the part where I automatically add email addresses and simply use the completions.

Comment: Yeah. I had to take it offline. Most of it is gleaned from emacswiki though.